# Array of objects to array of indices

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an array with unique objects and another array that contains objects from the first array, I need an array of indices that contains the index of every object in the first array.

Example:

```
var a = new MyClass(1);
var b = new MyClass(2);
var c = new MyClass(3);
MyClass[] firstArray = {a, b, c}; // these all are unique
MyClass[] secondArray = {b, a, a, c, b};
```

In this case the output would be `{2, 1, 1, 3, 2}`

This could obviously be done by comparing every object inside nested loops, but this would result in O(n*m) complexity. Is there a more optimal solution for this problem?

Comment: Use HashSet or Dictionary for lookup. Their complexities are O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the first array and build a `Dictionary<T, int>` holding the index of each item.

Loop through the second array and look up each item in the dictionary.

`O(n + m)`.

Comment: Don't forget to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, if you want to use objects of type `MyClass` as keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Unless you want reference equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = firstArray.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).ToDictionary(x => x.x, x => x.i);
var result = secondArray.Select(x => dict[x]).ToArray();
```

It gives you *O(n+m)*, because `Dictionary` lookup runs in *O(1)*.

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do here is a `Join`, conceptually, and that'll do most of the work.  We just need to first project the first sequence to a sequence that also includes its index, use the actual item as the join key, and the index as the result.

```
var indexes = from second in secondArray
                join first in firstArray.Select((item, i) => new { item, i })
                on second equals first.item
                select first.i;
```